# +x option for sort in Linux Programming?

Tags: linux

I am learning Unix/Linux programming from: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/

I want to print all the files containing the word 'test' in home directory, sorted according to their name. So I do following command:

```
ls -la | grep "test.*" | sort +6
```

The +6 is to ignore the first 6 columns and sort based on 7th column which is name of file.
But I get following error:

```
sort: cannot read: +6: No such file or directory
```

What is going wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: `sort +n` is an obsolete option that has been replaced by the `-k` option. That tutorial is outdated :)

Comment: Do you want to search in the **names** of the files, or the **files themselves** ?

Comment: @Gilles: I have many files starting with test like test1, ... test7: I want to list them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [manpages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) don't say anything about a `+` parameter. It seems you're looking for `sort -k 6`:

> -k, --key=KEYDEF
>   sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Linux coding.

First, one thing to start from: [don't parse `ls` output](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

```
printf '%s\n' *test* | sort -V
```

Comment: `-n` is probably better than `-V`; the output will be the same, but file size is a natural number, not a version number.

Comment: No, for a mixed sorting, `-V` is better and more logical, consider this example: https://gist.github.com/sputnick-dev/0c788e4307bea1167246d690ae14bc72

Answer (score 2):

You tutorial seems to be pretty bad.

My `sort` doesn't take `+` symbol. Check `man sort`. Looks like it treats any argument that doesn't start with a dash as a file name, hence the error.

That said, you don't need `grep` to filter for test, you can just have the shell do that (shell globbing):

```
ls -l test.*
```

`ls` can also sort, so you may not need to pipe into `sort` either. `ls` supports

- `-t` modification time
- `-S` file size
- `-X` extension

Use `-r` to reverse sort order. See `man ls` for details.